# Assets not being loaded (libGDX)

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, libgdx, textures

So I've made a small desktop application in Eclipse (gradle project) based on libGDX. Runs perfectly in Eclipse. When I export as a "runnable JAR file" (with Package required libraries into generated JAR checked) I get a warning: "**Fat Jar Export: Could not find class-path entry for 'D:Project TI Helper/core/bin/default/**".

Is something missing in the manifest at "**Class-Path: .**" ?
[image]

I have no idea what this is about. But the JAR is certainly not runnable. So I try the command prompt and do "**gradle desktop:dist --stacktrace**". Then the JAR file seems to be produced without any errors or warnings. So I go to .../desktop/build/libs/ and try to run it with "**java -jar desktop-1.0.jar**", the texture packer starts packing but fails in the end with this message in the console.[image]

The generated atlas-file IS in the specified location. The textures WERE packed. Why on earth is it not loading the stuff?? Btw, I'm using Java version **1.8.0_241** for both JDK and JRE.

**EDIT**
So it fails in the Assets class at "TextureAtlas atlas = assets2d.get(Cn.TEXTURES);". Going deeper into the AssetManager

```
    public synchronized <T> T get (String fileName) {
        Class<T> type = assetTypes.get(fileName);
        if (type == null) throw new GdxRuntimeException("Asset not loaded: " + fileName);         
       ...
```

So it seems the string provided is not pointing to my atlas-file. Cn.TEXTURES is defined as "../desktop/assets/atlas/textures.atlas". That raises the question: How DO you write the path?

DesktopLauncher.java

```
public class DesktopLauncher
{   
    public static boolean rebuildAtlas = true;
    public static boolean drawDebugOutline = true;

    public static void main (String[] arg)
    {
        // Build Texture Atlases
        if (rebuildAtlas) {
            Settings settings = new Settings();
            settings.maxWidth = 2048;
            settings.maxHeight = 2048;
            settings.pot = false;
            settings.combineSubdirectories = true;

            // Pack images in "textures" folder
            TexturePacker.process("assets/textures", "assets/atlas", "textures.atlas");

        }   

        LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();

        cfg.title = "TI Helper";
        cfg.useGL30 = false;
        cfg.width = Cn.RESOLUTION_WIDTH;
        cfg.height = Cn.RESOLUTION_HEIGHT;
        cfg.fullscreen = true;

        new LwjglApplication(new TIHelper(), cfg);

    }
}
```

Assets.java

```
public class Assets implements Disposable, AssetErrorListener
{
    public static final String TAG = Assets.class.getName();
    public static final Assets instance = new Assets();

    // Asset managers
    public AssetManager assets2d;

    public AssetDeco assetDeco;
    public AssetFonts fonts;
    public AssetMisc assetMisc;

    // General fonts
    public static Font not16, not20, not24, dig16;

    // Singelton: prevent installation from other classes
    private Assets() {}

    public void init ()
    {

        // Init 2D graphics manager
        init2DAssetManager();

        TextureAtlas atlas = assets2d.get(Cn.TEXTURES);          
        // Cn.TEXTURES == String TEXTURES = "../desktop/assets/atlas/textures.atlas";

        // Create game resource objects
        fonts = new AssetFonts();
        assetDeco = new AssetDeco(atlas);
        assetMisc = new AssetMisc(atlas);

        // Create fonts
        not16 = new Font(Assets.instance.fonts.notalot_16);
        not20 = new Font(Assets.instance.fonts.notalot_20);
        not24 = new Font(Assets.instance.fonts.notalot_24);
        dig16 = new Font(Assets.instance.fonts.digits_16);
    }

    private void init2DAssetManager()
    {
        // Create the manager
        assets2d = new AssetManager();
        // Set asset manager error handler
        assets2d.setErrorListener(this);
        // Load texture atlas
        assets2d.load(Cn.TEXTURES, TextureAtlas.class);
        // Start loading assets and wait until finished
        assets2d.finishLoading();

        // Prompt output
        Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "# of assets loaded: " + assets2d.getAssetNames().size);
        for (String a : assets2d.getAssetNames())
            Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "asset: " + a);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose ()
    {
        assets2d.dispose();
    }

    public void error (String filename, Class<?> type, Throwable throwable) {
        Gdx.app.error(TAG, "Couldn't load asset '" + filename + "'", (Exception)throwable);
    }            
    ...
```

Desktop build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = ["../desktop/assets"]

project.ext.mainClassName = "com.ti.desktop.DesktopLauncher"
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../desktop/assets")

task run(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
}

task debug(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
    debug = true
}

task dist(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
    dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    with jar
}

dist.dependsOn classes

eclipse.project.name = appName + "-desktop"
```

Workspace build.gradle

```
buildscript {


    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {


    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "ti-helper"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.10'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.8'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-desktop:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"

    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
        api "net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils:libgdx-utils:0.13.4"
        api "net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils:libgdx-utils-box2d:0.13.4"

    }
}
```

If someone could help me out it would much appreciated. This is my first project in libGDX and I'm very stuck here, and I'm all out of ideas on how to find any clues to what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and removing the ".atlas" from the filename fixed it. Although that is the file type, when I open my atlas file's properties in Windows explorer, the file type is simply listed as "file" rather than atlas.